# jQuery optimizing access to attributes for hover event

Tags: jquery, css, animation, mouseover, css-sprites

I am using CSS Image sprites for roll over effect on a element, the new class to be applied on mouse over is assigned to attribute `data-toggle-class` and below is the code ( I now this is  miniature performance improvement and doing pre-optimization which is not good)

```
    $("*[data-toggle-class]").hover(function(ev){
        var a = $(this);
        a.toggleClass(a.attr("data-toggle-class"))
    });
```

- how do I cache `data-toggle-class` attribute rather than retrieving it every time the hover occurs.
- Even though I use Image sprite there is small lag before the switch effect happens. Is this known issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer the question about caching *(mostly, see note under the divider below)*, which you can do with a closure:

```
$("*[data-toggle-class]").each(function() {
    var $elm = $(this),
        cls = $elm.attr('data-toggle-class');
    $elm.hover(function() {
        $elm.toggleClass(cls);
    });
});
```

What that does is, instead of having a single function that gets called for all of the matching elements during hover events, it generates a separate function for each element, where the function closes over a reference to a jQuery wrapper for the element and a copy of its `data-toggle-class` attribute. It trades off size (more functions = more memory, though you'd have to have a **lot** of these for it to start to matter) for speed.

If your goal is to have the class on hover and not have it when not hovering, I'd probably do that explicitly:

```
$("*[data-toggle-class]").each(function() {
    var $elm = $(this),
        cls = $elm.attr('data-toggle-class');
    $elm.hover(
        // Start hover
        function() {
            $elm.addClass(cls);
        },
        // Stop hover
        function() {
            $elm.removeClass(cls);
        }
    );
});
```

You've said

> I know this is miniature performance improvement and doing pre-optimization which is not good

...but I'd just like to underscore that. The above will work, probably won't cause excessive memory use, and will result in a ***tiny*** performance enhancement, but I tend to think that enhancement will be below the threshold of human perception.

---

I wonder if you really need the class, and the JavaScript code, at all? Unless you need to support IE6, the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class is exactly for this purpose, and is handled natively by the browser rather than by JavaScript code (read: faster). For instance:

```
[data-toggle-class] {
    color: green;
}
[data-toggle-class]:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

...will make any element with a `data-toggle-class` attribute green normally, but blue when hovered. If you need to do different things based on the *value* of the attribute, you can do that:

```
[data-toggle-class='foo'] {
    color: green;
}
[data-toggle-class='foo']:hover {
    color: blue;
}
[data-toggle-class='bar'] {
    color: black;
}
[data-toggle-class='bar']:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Elements with `data-toggle-class="foo"` will be green normally, blue when hovered; ones with `data-toggle-class="bar"` will be black normally, and red when hovered. No JavaScript required.

In the above you understand `color` is just an example; I expect you're using `background` and `background-position` if you're using sprites.

---

Here's a proper example of the CSS technique ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ucunel) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ucunel/edit#html)):

CSS:

```
.arrow {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png);
    background-repeat: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.style1 {
    background-position: 0px -220px;
}
.style1:hover {
    background-position: 0px -320px;
}
.style2 {
    background-position: 0px -260px;
}
.style2:hover {
    background-position: 0px -290px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow style1"></div>
<div class="arrow style2"></div>
```

Note how you can readily control which arrow appears, declaratively, with no JavaScript. Now, of course, if your conditions for which arrow should appear are more complicated than that, you may well have to go to JS. I'm just saying, for most simple hover ops, it's not needed.

Comment: the problem with having `:hover` is that , It does not suit the way i set it up here, for instance i Got right arrow(css sprite image) on a element and whose hover i want hovered image(again a css sprite) this would make a code like below in css `.right-arrow{} .right-arrow:hover{background-position:something}` but i actually got this `right-arrow{} right-arrow-hover{}` so that i can apply `right-arrow-hover` to any element regardless of it's state. so that would make me write code like below `/*display red arrow on hover*/right-arrow:hover{background-position:red-arrow-position}`

Comment: sorry the comment was soo long that i had to split that up  quote -which makes all right arrows show red arrow on hover. By doing this javascript way i get to customize which arrow shows up during hover event

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Right, but you can do that purely with CSS and markup. If all you're doing in the `hover` is adding a class, then you're already doing all the styling with CSS anyway. I've added a complete sprite example to the answer. Obviously, pick whichever approach suits you best.